# Trigger Volume Up key press in Android with Bluetooth in Node.js

Tags: camera, bluetooth, android, node.js

I'm making an app in Node.js and I need to make a remote shutter for Android's camera via Bluetooth.

I'm using Bleno/Noble libraries to achieve Bluetooth connection. As far as I know, selfie sticks use HID service on BLE and trigger volume up key press event, because phones usually take photos that way. I'd like to do the same trick.

So the question is, how do I tell the phone that I pressed the volume up button (even though I didn't physically press anything)? I'm NOT asking about the code that receives the event on the phone (almost all topics I found searching were about that).

Thank you in advance. If you need any further info don't hesitate to ask.